# react-hook-form version 7 validation errors not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm having problems with validation errors using the new react-hook-form version 7 and was wondering if anyone can help (see example linked below).

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-adapting-existing-form-forked-n3sis?file=/src/index.js

This all used to work until I updated from v6 to v7. I changed the way `register` was used, i.e. `{...register('name', {required: 'Add this'})}` instead of `ref={register({required: 'Add this'})}` and have updated getting the errors from formState now, i.e. `const { formState: { errors }} = useForm();` instead of `const { errors } = useForm();`.

I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with me using a controlled component rather than just a native html `<input />` but can't quite seem to figure it out.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to pass down props and ref to the input component.

```
const Input = React.forwardRef(
  ({ error, id, label, required, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <>
        <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
        <input id={id} required={required} {...props} ref={ref} />
        <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</span>
      </>
    );
  }
);
```

Here is your codesandbox working: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-adapting-existing-form-forked-dpxie?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer, glad it was something simple. I really like the simplicity of react-hook-form and was hoping it wasn't that the version bump had changed something drastically and made life more complicated.

Comment: Which additional props does it actually require as in this example we're just spreading all props, where as in my team world example I'd rather be in a little more control as to what can be passed through, i.e. I wouldn't want `className` being passed and added and overriding existing defined styles.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted around two days just to find out that I was the one who caused the problem.

I disabled submit button if the `formState.isValid` was `false`. But the default useForm validation `mode` is `onSubmit`. In this mode errors only show up when you submit the form and it was impossible because I disabled the button.

`mode` change to `onBlur` or `onChange` solved the problem